# how to connect phone to laptop

Tags: 14.04

i want to connect my phone to my laptop (ubuntu 14.04 LTS)
but if I plug in my (huawei y300 android 4.1 jellybean) i dont see a icon of my phone and there isn't something in files too. so does someone know how to do this?

btw my laptop doesn't have bluetooth

thanks for all help :D

Comment: Is MTP enabled on your phone?

Comment: what is MTP? :s

Comment: Media Transfer Protocol

Comment: no i dont have that :(

Comment: Go to `Settings`->`Storage`. Click the menu on the top right and go to `USB Computer Connection`. Select `Media Device(MTP)`.

Comment: i was searching on my phone and i found mtp so i had it but i didn't know :p. well it works thank you for the help :D

Comment: @RohithMadhavan: Could you post that as an answer so future posters can benefit from your wisdom and people like me hunting for unanswered questions know not to bother...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Install the following tools in Ubuntu to enable MTP support

`sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs`

On your Android phone, go to `Settings`->`Storage`.

Click the menu on the top right and go to `USB Computer Connection`. Select `Media Device(MTP)`.

Now you should be able to access your phone storage.